# Solidity: which method should I use to call a function of an external Contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

When using solidity, I have a doubt when I need to call a function which was created in a different contract. I know 2 ways of doing it, and I don't understand what is more recommendable and why. These are the ways I know:

**Method 1:**

```
contract A {
  function foo() external {
    return true;
  }
}

contract B is A {
  foo();
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
contract A {
  function foo() external {
    return true;
  }
}

contract B {
  function callFoo() external {
    A a = A(addressA);
    return a.foo();
  }
}
```

Could anyone tell me the differences, and when it is more convenient wo user wither Method 1 or Method 2?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 is used when you're calling a contract that is deployed on the **same address**. It can be either a parent of your `Contract B` or a library that your contract has imported.

Since the `foo` method is `external`, you'd need to call it using `this.foo();`.

> *An external function f cannot be called internally (i.e. f() does not work, but this.f() works).*

Source: [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters)

If it were `public`, you could call it internally, just using `foo()`.

---

Method 2 is used when you're calling a contract that is deployed on a **different address**.

Your `Contract B` than doesn't have to redefine the `Contract A`, and can only define the interface:

```
// this is just an interface of an external contract
interface A {
  function foo() external returns (bool);
}

// this is your contract
contract B {
  function callFoo() external returns (bool) {
    A a = A(addressA);
    return a.foo();
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case, Method 1 can still be used if both contracts are in different addresses, but you use the "import" keyword to bring contract A from a GIT for example, right? Then, I assume that by using Method 2 you don't need to import the contract A, meaning the cost could be much reduced compared to Method 1. Could you please confirm that?

Comment: If your `contract A` is imported and `contract B` derives from it, they're going to be deployed on the same address. Nevertheless, another instance of `contract A` may be deployed on another address, but the Method 1 will not be able to access the remote `contract A` (it doesn't have its remote address) - only the local `contract A` ... "by using Method 2 you don't need to import the contract A" - That's correct ... "cost could be much reduced" - It depends. You may still need to deploy both contracts. But if the remote `Contract A` is deployed by someone else, you save the deployment fees.

Comment: Okay, so assuming `ContractA`  is deployed by someone else, then when using Method 2 I am just creating a pointer to `ContractA`, without deploying it again, right? On the other hand, when using Method 1  `ContractB is ContractA` then I am indeed deploying both and consuming more gas. If what I am saying is correct, then I understood completely your answer :)